# toggle button mouse listener null pointer exception

Tags: java, mouselistener, togglebutton

I'm creating a version of Minesweeper in java, but am having issues setting up the mouse listener for the toggleButtons. I need to do different things on left and right click, so this is what I've setup so far in my MyPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        JToggleButton jButtons[] = new JToggleButton[100];
        int i = 0;

        MyFrame frame;
        JLabel testOut;
        gameEngine engine;

        public MyPanel(MyFrame mf) {
            for (i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
                jButtons[i] = new JToggleButton("");
                jButtons[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) { //**Exception here**
                            engine.markCell(i);
                            System.out.println("L-click");
                        } else if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) { //**or here**
                            engine.showCell(i);
                            System.out.println("R-click");
                        }
                    }
                });
            //System.out.print(i);
            add(jButtons[i]);
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }
```

however, I'm getting a 'nullPointerException' on one of the marked lines (depending on L or R-click):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
      at MyPanel$1.museReleased(MyPanel.java:31)
      at java.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
```

This seems to read like the 'MouseEvent' is throwing the exception, but I don't understand why is would, much less how to fix it.

Here are my other classes, so you can see what 'MyFrame' and 'gameEngine' refer to.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JToggleButton jButtons[] = new JToggleButton[100];

    gameEngine engine;
    MyPanel panel;

    public MyFrame() {
        setTitle("Minesweeper");
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new MyPanel(this);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public gameEngine getGame() {
        return engine;
    }
}
```

--

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/** model of minesweeper game: contains mine arrays, as well as methods
for left and right click responses.**/
public class gameEngine {

    private int[][] mines;
    private int Row;
    private int Col;

    //seed based random number generator
    double rnd(){
        int seed = 42;
        Random gen = new Random(seed);
        double output = gen.nextDouble();

        return output;
    }

    /*generate array to represent minefield. generated array will contain only 0s and 1s
    possible cases of array are:
    0: no mine, unmarked
    1: mine, unmarked
    2: no mine: marked
    3: mine: marked */

    //this method generates initial empty array, then calls layMines to populate it
    public void initField(){
        mines = new int[10][10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
                mines[i][j] = 0;
        layMines();
    }

    //lays 16 mines into the array using a random number generator
    public void layMines(){
        int minesOnField = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
                if (rnd() >=70) { //if roll is successful
                    if (minesOnField < 16){ //and less than 16 mines have been
                        if(mines[i][j] == 0) { //AND it isnt already a mine
                            minesOnField ++;
                            mines[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }                
    }

    public void showCell(int x) {
    }

    public void markCell(int x){

    }

    public void test() {
        initField();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mines));
    }

}
```

my 'main' method simply calls 'MyFrame.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared gameEngine as

```
gameEngine engine;
```

While you never initialized it and you used it like:

```
if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) { //**Exception here**
    engine.markCell(i);
    ...
} else if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) { //**or here**
    engine.showCell(i);
    ..
```

By default, objects are initialized as null if not intialized and any method call on null will lead to NullPointerException.

You should initialize engine.